# Login with Scrapy with site using Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I am trying to use `Scrapy` to pull more information from another page. I was able to login with my last project and am modeling this one after it. The login page for this particular site is much different, however. Here is the markup for the page with the relevant information provided:

```
<div id="form" style="display:inline;">

    <form id="login" class="gfimaxrmform2" name="gfimaxform" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return attemptLogin(this);" >

        <label for="username">User name:</label>
        <input alt="blank" size="30" id="username" name="username" type="text" />

        <br />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input alt="blank" size="30" id="password" name="password" type="password"  />

        <br />
        <br />
        <script type="text/javascript">document.write("<input name='url' id = 'url' type='hidden' value = '"+document.URL+"'>")</script>
        <div class="formfields_belowfields">
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to use my code to login and then go to another website but I am not sure how to make it `"click"` submit. Here is the code I am working on:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return[FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata = {"username" : user, "password": password}, callback = self.after_login)]
```

The `after_login' will just make sure that I am logged in, however it doesn't seem to be clicking the submit button to go to the next page.

edit: The link to the page I am trying to log in to is: [Here](http://www.gfimax.com/dashboard/remote-management/)

Comment: I'm not familiar with scrapy, but it might be useful to look at the `attemptLogin` function, construct a URL from what you find there, and then post your username/pass to it directly.

Comment: @Ryan All I see for `attemptLogin` is `onsubmit="return attemptLogin(this);" > ` Not sure where I would get a `URL` from. Thanks.

Comment: You could also open developer mode in your browser and analyze the network activity to get the URL to which the params are being posted.

Comment: Try to add `{'url': response.url}` to your FormRequest

Comment: @yhager That didn't seem to do it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `Selenium` to really simplify this process. If anyone discovers a need for something in the future I would recommend using it.

Comment: I suggest ```from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright``` You can use it as a headless browser as well